# Align animated list similiar to static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to align the animated list so that the margin at the top and bottom are equal, I want to center the 'finished' animated list within its parent div. The current CSS is shown in the code snippet. How can I center the list within its parent div without loosing the animation? (I managed to center it without the animation).

```js
      current = 1;
      $(".list-div ul li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("animate").css("animation-delay", current + 's');
        current++;
      });
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 75%;
}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list-div li.animate{
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 220px;
  }
  25%{
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content" id="list-cont">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul>
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the list-div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set  `.list-div{height:100%}` and remove the `margin-top: 15px` from `.list-div ul`

Comment: that does not work because only the first list item is 'centered' and the others are below

Comment: damn didn't even noticed I had this in :D

Comment: thats why it didnt work with my own solution as well, +1:)

Answer (score 1):

I documented the CSS changes in the source. It's mainly using the height definition for boxes correctly.

```js
current = 1;
$(".list-div ul li").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("animate").css("animation-delay", current + 's');
  current++;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content {
  /* position: relative; */
  margin: 0;
  /* height: 100%; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem 0; /* Value for top and bottom */
}

.list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  /* margin-top: 15%; */
  margin: 0;
  width: 75%;
}

.list-div li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* margin-bottom: 5px; */
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list-div li.animate {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 220px;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content" id="list-cont">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul>
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```